# How to have multiple <tr> elements sticky at once on a table

Tags: css, html-table, sticky

I am working on a tool that has a lot of very long tables. Some of these tables have multiple rows inside the `<thead>`, and I would like to have all of them be `position: sticky` at once. However, I cannot find a way to do this.

I tried adding `position: sticky` to the th, like so:

```
table thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

I also tried adding `position: sticky` to the entire thead, but it seems that there's [a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=702927) in Chromium that prevents this from working.

I am trying to achieve something like this:
[image: img]

Where both of the top two rows are kept sticky when the user scrolls past.

Is there a way to do this that works in both Chrome and Firefox? I do not need to support IE.

Comment: https://codepen.io/nirmalkc/pen/oswdB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the `<tr>` elements will have the same height, say 20px, then you could try something like

```
thead tr th {
    position: sticky;
}

thead tr:nth-of-type(1) th {
    top: 0;
}

thead tr:nth-of-type(2) th {
    top: 20px;
}

thead tr:nth-of-type(3) th {
    top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like it works: https://codepen.io/campbellbrendene/pen/PoYPKZw (tested on Chrome 75.0 on Windows 10)

Comment: @Brenden I have changed the css, and checked that it works in Chrome by changing your pen. I didn't realise the bug affected tr as well as th.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for